# Get Random Element from Collection

Tags: java

I have a `Collection<Obj>` how do I get a random `Obj` from it?

I've checked the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html) and there doesn't seem to be a way, since iterator is the only way to access the collection. Do I have to iterate over it to get a random object!?

Comment: Get a random int from the size() of the collection, i.e, `random.nextInt(collection.size())`, and iterate that number of times.

Comment: If you need random access so you need a List.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The most efficient it to only iterate as far as you need.

```
public static <T> T random(Collection<T> coll) {
    int num = (int) (Math.random() * coll.size());
    for(T t: coll) if (--num < 0) return t;
    throw new AssertionError();
}
```

Answer (score 58):

Using Lambdas you can do this quite quickly and handle the case when Collection is empty.

```
public static <E> Optional<E> getRandom (Collection<E> e) {

    return e.stream()
            .skip((int) (e.size() * Math.random()))
            .findFirst();
}
```

Comment: Liked this answer but made a small tweak to it:
`skip(new Random().nextInt(collection.size()))` instead of `skip((int) (e.size() * Math.random()))`

Comment: @BitfulByte this will not work with empty collections. `nextInt` argument should be >0

Answer (score 8):

```
private Object getRandomObject(Collection from) {
   Random rnd = new Random();
   int i = rnd.nextInt(from.size());
   return from.toArray()[i];
}
```

Comment: It seems somewhat wasteful to put the whole collection into an array just to get a single element.

Comment: @Keppil - won't that mean we never get the first item from the collection?

Comment: @Sridhar-Sarnobat: No, nextInt(max) returns a value from `0` to `max-1`.

Answer (score 5):

I know this is an old thread, but I'm surprised that nobody mentioned the `RandomAccess` interface which marks a `List` implementation as having a very fast access by index.

Here is `RandomAccess`'s documentation:

> Marker interface used by List implementations to indicate that they support fast (generally constant time) random access. The primary purpose of this interface is to allow generic algorithms to alter their behavior to provide good performance when applied to either random or sequential access lists.

For example: It is implemented by `ArrayList` in contrast to `LinkedList`.

This is my solution that takes advantage of it:

```
public static <E> E getRandomElement(Collection<E> collection) 
{
    if(collection.isEmpty()) 
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Cannot return a random value from an empty collection!");

    int randomIndex = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(collection.size());

    if(collection instanceof RandomAccess) 
        return ((List<E>) collection).get(randomIndex);

    for(E element : collection)
    {
        if(randomIndex == 0)
            return element;

        randomIndex--;
    }

    throw new IllegalStateException("How did we get here?"); //unreachable
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Several options (by order of efficiency):

- use a List instead of a Collection,
- generate a random index with random.nextInt(collection.size()), get an iterator and iterate,
- generate a random index with random.nextInt(collection.size()), convert the collection into an array with toArray(), and index that array.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind a 3rd party library, the [Utils](https://github.com/RKumsher/utils) library has a [IterableUtils](https://github.com/RKumsher/utils/blob/master/src/main/java/com/github/rkumsher/collection/IterableUtils.java) that has a randomFrom(Iterable iterable) method that will take a Collection and return a random element from it

```
Collection<Object> collection = ....;
Object random = IterableUtils.randomFrom(collection);
```

It is in the Maven Central Repository at:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.github.rkumsher</groupId>
  <artifactId>utils</artifactId>
  <version>1.3</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution using Google Guava [`Iterables.get()`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Iterables.html#get-java.lang.Iterable-int-) method:

```
private <T> T getRandomObject(Collection<T> from) {
   Random rnd = new Random();
   int i = rnd.nextInt(from.size());
   return Iterables.get(from, i);
}
```

If you want to handle empty collections as well, the [method with `defaultValue`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Iterables.html#get-java.lang.Iterable-int-T-) may be used: `Iterables.get(from, i, null)`

Answer (score 0):

One can use [`Stream#skip`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#skip-long-) along with [`ThreadLocalRandom`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadLocalRandom.html).

```
public static <T> T getRandomElement(final Collection<T> collection) {
    return Objects.requireNonNull(collection, "collection is null").stream()
      .skip(ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(Math.max(collection.size(), 1)))
      .findFirst().orElseThrow(() -> new IllegalArgumentException("collection is empty"));
}
```

Answer (score -4):

User `Collections.shuffle(list);`. Then you can just get the first element. It will be random.

or you can also do this

```
int size = list.size();
int item = new Random().nextInt(size); 
list.get(item )
```

Comment: You can't shuffle Collection because it takes List, this is what OP asked.